# 4 points, how to know if it's growing over time?

Tags: regression, statistical-inference

I've an array of 4 points, which formula should I use to detect their growth ?

`[ 18.84652397793915,
  18.905644902423617,
  18.90589218022171,
  18.282140258415314 ]`

The formula would give me something around 0.

`[ 22.864760626100246,
  21.442988092040103,
  34.690156329316174,
  32.12712981953433 ]`

The formula would give me something > 1.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know anything about regression?

Comment: But in your latter example, the value goes down, then up, and then back down. Why should it be greater than $1$?

Comment: Add some more information to your problem. Are these x and y coordinates of the points? How did you find these values etc? There are various techniques of fitting curves to points, but they usually imply that you already have a general function, which is supposed to fit. If you don't know anything about this data, then these are just some random coordinates. 4 points could define a polynomial of degree 3 or an ellipse or really anything else if errors are involved...

Comment: Ok sorry, I have a bunch of points (memory usage) and the garbage collector clean the memory automatically. But some times the memory keep growing (memory leak) and I want to detect this. I just looked at regression and this is what I need (https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't know exactly what the garbage collector is doing - and obviuosly you don't really know what your program is doing ;) - there is no way to decide what kind of growth you have. But it only seems to be relevant IF your numbers are growing over time or not. So you could assume linear growth and do a [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) for example with excel/calc. You could then try and find out, if the gradient is noticeably bigger than 0 or not. But you should gather some more values for this to be precise.